# Как реализовать поднятие по предкам при hover?

Tags: css

Есть данная разметка:

```
<div>
 <div class='hello'>
  <a href = "#">Hover me</a>
 </div>
 <div class = 'hovered'></div>
</div>
```

Нужно, что бы при ховере на Hover me отображался блок hovered

такой css не работает:

```
.hello a:hover .hovered { display:block }
```

Comment: если блок с классом `.hovered` положишь в `a` то заработает, твоя операция говорит что, в `.hello` если на `a` навели, в `a` показать блок `.hovered`

Comment: я понимаю, поэтому вопрос стоит в том , как подняться вверх по дереву. Положить в блок исключено

Comment: вверх ты не поднимешься, как и предыдущий элемент ты не можешь получить, только следующий, например ты можешь перенести `.hovered` в блок `.hello` тогда можешь использовать так `a:hover + .hovered { display: block; }`. Иначе пиши js

Comment: Тогда js активируем

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `CSS` не предусмотрено возвращение к предку. В `CSS4` обещают, но пока нет возможности использовать это, ибо черновик.

Делайте разметку `HTML` нормальную или используйте `JS`.

Answer (score 1):

При таком выборе селектора `parent:hover chlid` вы прописываете свойства для `child` при наведенном на `parent`. `child` должен быть внутри `parent`.